# Load Imageview in ViewHolder

Tags: java, android, picasso

So I am trying to load my Image from the databse into my ImageView in my ViewHolader. The Way I do it an error appears: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main!
I am trying to load it with Picasso, but it doens't let me. 
Whats the right way to show it ?

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.nametext.setText(usersList.get(i).getBenutername());
    viewHolder.orttext.setText(usersList.get(i).getOrt());
    Picasso.get().load(usersList.get(i).getImage());


    final String user_id = usersList.get(i).userId;

    viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "User ID:"+user_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

        nametext = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.name_text);
        image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        orttext = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.ort_text);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way :

```
  if (usersList!=null&&usersList.get(i).getImage()!=null&&usersList.get(i).getImage().isEmpty()) {
  viewHolder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.anydefaultimage);
   } else{
   Picasso.get().load(usersList.get(i).getImage()).into(viewHolder.image);
  }
```

Comment: let me know if still stuck?

Comment: Alright I understand why but it is still not working on this part. With this errpr: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mind.simplelogin, PID: 30564
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty.

Comment: updated code try to understand if still suck let me know

Comment: No, still doenst work. I tried with an if Statement as well earlier. Did not work

Comment: are you still getting crash?

Comment: yes:  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.isEmpty()' on a null object reference

Comment: bro its a different issues is NullPointerException previously is was IllegalArgumentException and this is happening because your getImage() method return null.

Comment: upvote is it helped you and let me know if still stuck?

Comment: It heldep, i found my mistake. What you worte was perfectly fine